# Why does inotitywait with "echo '---' >> file" only emit an "OPEN" event?

Tags: shell, inotify

Why does `echo "---" >> file` only generate a `./ OPEN file` event?  Shouldn't it generate other events too?

For example:

```
# In a script:
while true; do
  change=$(inotifywait -q -r . )
  echo $change
done

# Somewhere else:
echo "--" >> file
echo "--" >> file
echo "--" >> file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is exiting after the first event and starting the loop over, by the time the first watch is removed and the second added, the events have already transpired.  You can try:

```
inotifywait -q -m -r . | while read CHANGE; do
    case "$CHANGE" in
        *)echo $CHANGE;;
    esac
done
```

the -m will continue monitoring after the first event

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you so much.

Comment: I recall when I first used the inotify* apps that a lot of the operations seemed counter-intuitive without the help of manpages (http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait btw).  The C interface is quite nice though.

Comment: For some reason I overlooked using `while read` even though I knew about `-m` in the man pages. It's so embarrassing.

Comment: `while-read-case` should be the basis for any shell scripting tutorial - with a little substring manipulation it can replace many (slow) external calls to awk,sed,grep,cut,tr etc... Although the case is unnecessary to answer your question as asked, having it there may future changes a bit more obvious if you want to filter the output.  And since inotifywait can format the output you can use extra read variables and/or substring manipulation to do what you want with it.